# How can I get more information on a Event Viewer - Windows Logs error?

Tags: windows, asp.net, eventviewer

An application i wrote is throwing the error (in my application Log):

```
 SocialNetworking.Facebook 
   b0ceb124-b183-4b66-aa10-39fd9e142bn4 
 Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, 
   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=736440c9b414ea16' or one of its dependencies. 
   The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've registered the assembly in the GAC so i'm not sure where it's looking for this.  Is there any way to find out where it's looking or maybe to get a stack trace for the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run SysInternals (Microsoft) ProcessMonitor ([here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)) to see which file it's looking for.